# Can I circumvent my ISP blocking my chosen DNS servers?

Tags: windows-10, dns, isp

My ISP suddenly started blocking my DNS (I was using google 8.8.8.8 DNS and 1.1.1.1)

I could ping to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1, but no access to DNS service.

I could not ping to any web address.

I was able to get yo youtube's webpage but without any video or image. That was the only website on all of internet that I could access, and I suspect that it was because Firefox cached some DNS data.

When I configure the WiFi adapter's TCP4 properties to use automatic DNS, then all works fine, but when I specify my preferred DNS servers, it all stop working.

I have Firefox to use encrypted DNS over https using Cloudfare, but it only works when the DNS server is setup to automatic on the network adapter.

I do not want my ISP having any say on the DNS I choose.

The ISP is evil, sometimes redirects my web pages, and also replaces ads, so I frequently get complain from web pages that I'm not supporting them by using an ad block, which is not true.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change ISPs, and don't even think about doing any financial transactions through this ISP.

Comment: There are [more DNS servers](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-dns-server) to use other than Google and Cloudflare ones **but** consider changing your ISP since the ISP is trying to **censor** you.

Comment: @CaldeiraG - or trying to divert click revenue (that bit about replacing ads)...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yeah, that is kinda scary.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/250008/how-can-i-tell-if-my-isp-is-redirecting-my-dns-queries?rq=1

Comment: If you cannot change ISPs, use an encrypted DNS proxy.

Answer (score 1):

First, consult your ISP's technical folks, and ask why.

If they provide an arbitrary or irrelevant answer, look for alternate DNS providers they don't block.

Once they block all satisfactory alternate DNS providers, change your ISP. or as suggested by [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b), use an encrypted DNS proxy.